# Is deleting all rows in an R data frame using [-0,] officially supported?

Tags: r

I have found that I can delete all rows of an R data frame by subsetting with the square bracket function and using -0 as the row index. However, I have not been able to find any documentation saying this is an official behavior that I can count on being there in the future. Is this an official function that I can use with confidence expecting that it will continue to function that way in future releases?

```
> df <- data.frame(c1=c(1,2,3),c2=c(2,3,4), c3=c(4,5,6))
> df
  c1 c2 c3
1  1  2  4
2  2  3  5
3  3  4  6  
> df[-0,]
[1] c1 c2 c3
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Indexing start from 1.  So, `df[0,]` will be all 0 rows

Comment: Note that it doesn't have to be -0; it can just be 0. And as akrun mentioned, this is the expected result of selecting rows with index 0.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that would change, but nothing in life is certain. `df[integer(0),]` does the same thing and feels little more...."sophisticated". :)

Comment: I can't find any official documentation either, but if you're looking for something that definitely is documented and will work in the future and has the same effect, try df[c(),]

Comment: @EricBrooks: Can you provide a link to documentation regarding `df[c(),]`?

Comment: @AlexA. "R language definition" 3.4.1 Indexing by vectors: "**NULL**. This is treated as if it were integer(0)." and `c()` is documented to return `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's check the documentation.

`help("[.data.frame")` says (emphasis mine):

> When [ and [[ are used with two indices (x[i, j] and x[[i, j]]) they
>   act like indexing a matrix [...]. Note that for each selected column,
>   xj say, typically (if it is not matrix-like), **the resulting column
>   will be xj[i], and hence rely on the corresponding [ method**, see the
>   examples section.

Next stop is `help("[")`, which doesn't say anything about using 0 as an index, but points to the ‘R Language Definition’ manual.

[There](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing) we read (emphasis mine):

> A special case is the zero index, which has null effects: **x[0] is an
>   empty vector** and otherwise including zeros among positive or
>   negative indices has the same effect as if they were omitted.

**In summary:**

Since this behavior is documented, you can rely on `DF[0,]` returning a data.frame with empty column vectors.

Comment: I don't get the "same effect as if they were omitted part", df[] is very different from df[-0,]. But you did find somewhere in the documentation that explicitly says x[0] is an empty vector.

Comment: @tlarchuk It means that if you do `df[0:5,]` you get the same result as if you omit the 0, i.e., `df[1:5,]`.